# How does Android device when factory wiped still remember app activation code?

Tags: android, google-play

When a user has paid for a premium subscription app what happens to the activation code if that device is then factory wiped? It cannot be stored in SharedPreferences - what about Google Play? I've noticed some apps are able to recover the activation codes after factory wipes. How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely because they are stored in the cloud, at their servers, and when you reconnect with a recognized account they know it. That recognized account may as well be the Google-account. Windows 8 metro comes for instance with their own cloud-based storage for applications linked to peoples live-accounts

Also some apps may store an activation-file on the SD-card or to file. Factory swipe does not always mean a formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The shared preferences can be backed-up and restored to Google's cloud, or more specifically:

https://developers.google.com/android/backup/